# UIImage size changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, constraints

I am trying to create a quiz app that gets the questions from a web database. Some questions have pictures and some do not. I want the images to take up all the free area of the screen (without changing the aspect radio). I cannot fix the position of the pictures because the question text varies greatly in length. 
When I click "Start Game" I get the first question just like I want it to look (Image 1) but then just fraction of a second later my view seems to redraw it self and the image pushes the question text down. (Image 2)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

This is the function that I use to update my view:

```
- (void) loadCurrentQuestion {
    [loadDialog dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = [[[@"Spurning " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", nr]] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", numOfQuestions]];
    tapToContinue = NO;
    //question.text = currQuestion.question;
    question.text = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";


    //[image setNeedsDisplay];
    //[question setNeedsDisplay];


    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [c1 setTitle: [currQuestion getAnswer:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    c1.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    c2.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    c3.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    c4.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;

    [c2 setTitle: [currQuestion getAnswer:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c3 setTitle: [currQuestion getAnswer:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c4 setTitle: [currQuestion getAnswer:4] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [c1 setEnabled:YES];
    [c2 setEnabled:YES];
    [c3 setEnabled:YES];
    [c4 setEnabled:YES];
    [c1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [c2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [c3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [c4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    if (!(currQuestion.image == (id)[NSNull null]) ) {
        if ([currQuestion.image length] > 1000)
            image.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [[ImageProcessing alloc] stringToImage: currQuestion.image]];
        else
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question_no_image.jpg"];
    } 
    else
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question_no_image.jpg"];

    //[loadDialog dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
}
```

I am pretty sure that I am using the correct constraints in my Storyboard since the correct look appears in the beginning. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: so you need solution for fixing image position irrespective of size?

Comment: the image will be loaded according to the size of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
 To the below method send your image and the size for the image you need this will not spoil aspect ration and fix the image size in that view

+(UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect forImageViewRect:(CGSize)imageVwRect{

//  UIImage *tempImage;
// tempImage=[self scaleImage:imageToCrop toSize:imageVwRect];

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

//  cropped=[self scaleImage:cropped toSize:rect.size];
return cropped;
}
```